# How many of each ticket were sold in one day?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

Child tickets - $\$7$

Adult Tickets - $\$10$

Senior Tickets - $\$5$

Day one sold $678$ tickets for $\$5,812$

Day two sold $535$ tickets for $\$4,541$

How many of each ticket were sold on day one and two?

If someone could even just explain how to set it up or what method to use I would appreciate it a lot. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Let $x$ be the number of child tickets sold, $y$ adults, and $z$ seniors. Then we know for day one 
$$
\$x + \$y + \$z = \$ 5812
$$ 
and 
$$
x + y + z = 678.
$$ 
What are the dollar amounts associated with $x,y$, and $z$? What does day two look like?

Comment: x=7 y=10 and z=5 day two is the same variables with the same dollar value but 535 tickets were sold and there was $4, 541 made

Comment: @Vicki Yes. Now you have a system with 4 equations and three unknowns. That is an overdetermined system. You should edit your post to show the system of equations you came up with.

Answer (score -1):

Child tickets - $7

Adult Tickets - $10

Senior Tickets - $5

A is the number of Adult tickets, C is the number of Child tickets, and S is the number of Senior tickets in what follows below.

A1 + C1 + S1 = 678 (Day 1)

A2 + C2 + S2 = 535 (Day 2)

Solution:

Day one: Sold tickets 678 for $5,812

A1 = 420, C1 = 161, S1 = 97 (Day 1)

Day two: Sold tickets 535 for $4,541

A2 = 215, C2 = 38, S2 = 425 (Day 2)

It must be remembered that other answers are also possible.

Comment: It may help Readers if you include the definitions of the variables in your "setup".  While it is tempting to interpret $A$ as the number of Adult tickets, $C$ as the number of Child tickets, and $S$ as the number of Senior tickets, the conflation of day one and day two information needs to be explained.